# Show specific window over unity bar

Tags: unity, launcher, window

I have a dual monitor setup where I show the unity launcher on both screens without autohiding, so the bars are always on top. Now I'd like to play Rocket League splitscreen spanned on both screens. I just let the game run in borderless window with resolution 3840x1080, which works fine, except that the Unity bars are now on top of the window. Is it possible to tell the Unity bar to stay behind that specific window?

Cheers

Comment: Are you referring to the launcher as in the one with apps, or the top panel which displays window menus,network,session, and time indicators ? Launcher can be hidden, panel cannot ( unless a window is in fullscreen mode)

Comment: I'm referring to the launcher on the left side. I know that it can be hidden, but I usually have set it to always be shown. I'd like to know if it is possible to leave it like this and only show certain windows on top of it

Comment: As far as I know, not possible. I will try a couple things tomorrow, but I am 98% positive unity launcher is built to stay on top of all windows

Comment: Ok thanks. I will also try out a few things, but so far I haven't found anything.